# Django inline has no ForeignKey but has one?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, inlines

I want to try to add a ListField increasible on django admin. I discover I can do that with inlines, so I goes to the doc to find this code :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**admin.py**

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

I simply copy this code to see how it render on Django admin page.
But the following error appear :

*<class 'users.admin.BookInline'>: (admin.E202) 'users.Book' has no ForeignKey to 'users.Book'.*

I don't understand why because Book as a ForeignKey. Am I missing something ?

Thx

Comment: You seem to have added Authoradmin to the Book model instead of to the Author model (in the register line).

Comment: Ho god thx you ! Sorry for the, I realize it now, novice question. I'm new on django